# How do I use adaptative learning rate when training a transformer model?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

So I am trying to use adaptative learning rate instead of a fixed one when training a transformer model. I have never done this with Pytorch and Transformers and although I have found some [documentation](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/en/main_classes/optimizer_schedules) I have not been able to reproduce it. Could someone help me, I am a beginner. Help is much appreciated.

My code:

```
training_args = TrainingArguments(
#auto_find_batch_size=True,
per_device_train_batch_size=8,
per_device_eval_batch_size=8,
evaluation_strategy=IntervalStrategy.STEPS,
eval_steps=50,
gradient_accumulation_steps=4,
num_train_epochs=7,
warmup_steps=500,
weight_decay=0.01,
learning_rate=None,
bf16=True,
logging_steps=10,
save_steps=500,
output_dir=OUTPUT_DIR,
report_to="all",
run_name="oxford_gemma",
load_best_model_at_end=True, 
metric_for_best_model='loss',
#logging_dir='./logs',
optim="paged_adamw_8bit"
)

print("Starting training with the updated configuration")

try:
  trainer = SFTTrainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=val_dataset,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    data_collator=data_collator,
    callbacks=[EarlyStoppingCallback(early_stopping_patience=3)]
)

trainer.train()

except OutOfMemoryError:
   print("Ran out of memory during training. Try reducing the batch size or sequence length.")
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
```